# How bad it is to work in Amsterdam and live in Leiden?

Tags: netherlands, accommodation

I will work in Amsterdam soon, and I found an accommodation in Leiden

I'm worried about commuting every day

How bad it is please?

My home will be 10 minutes walking to the train, and then I will need a train to Amsterdam (maybe 40 minutes), then metro 3 minutes to the company.

Comment: If you have direct train then I don't think it is big problem or so. You can read books or work on the laptop on the train. If you willing then you can buy a foldable bike to cover the distance from home to station and from station to work. If so you will have free daily exercises and good mood to start with. The trains might be packed at the rush hours but I think you always should find a place in the train or even start earlier to avoid big crowds.

Comment: **Where in Amsterdam** is relevant to the because there are more train stations.

Comment: @EugenMartynov "foldable bike": it would likely be easier to buy a second bike and keep one in each town.

Answer (score 4):

The train is more like 35 min and you can shave off 5 min from the total by having a bike and leaving it at the station in Leiden. That's what most locals would do in your situation. The trains can be packed but you will often find a seat. They are not the most reliable either, in the winter I think we get disruptions once a week or so.

Another angle to consider is that your employer might cover the transportation costs, tax-free. You have to check your contract and collective agreement (CAO) to see if something like that applies to you.

That's about all that can be said that would be specific to the situation. For the rest, a 45 min commute in Amsterdam is like a 45 min commute elsewhere. It does impact your overall quality of life and is longer than what I would wish for myself. But that's just an opinion and I also know many people who do much more, you'll have to make that decision for yourself.

Comment: I am afraid it will be more than 45 minutes, specially in winter, as you said, trains are not reliable. The issue is I dont know the country and the agency needs an answer from me tomorrow!!!! another advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: But what kind of information about the country are you expecting? My guess is that it should be 45-50 min on most days maybe an hour if you are unlucky. That's basically what I wrote in the answer and I stand by it but if you don't believe me, I can't help you. I have friends and colleagues who commute between Amsterdam and Rotterdam or Amsterdam and Delft for example, I wouldn't do it but it's not uncommon. On the other hand, I cannot make the decision for you or tell you whether this is good or bad, that's something you have to figure out yourself based on this information.

Comment: okay thank you, the compay pays 200 per month max, do you think I will need to pay a lot ? becaue I beliebe 200 is not engough right?

Comment: 2nd class travel from Leiden CS to Amsterdam CS is €231.= per month if you have a year subscription. Add the metro costs to that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Gala's [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/12135/7110):

I live in Amsterdam these days, and only bike to work - ~15 min door to door. Before, I used to commute - although not in the Netherlands. I was once working somewhere that was 10 min + 70 min train + 5 min walk; and another time, a 25-45 min drive.

I can't tell you how much better it makes me feel having to commute less, or nearly not at all. It's like work is an entirely different experience. Daily commutes, especially long ones, wear you down in my experience. It makes your day a sort of a burden, adds a long period of self-sacrifice or self denial. So while it's perfectly doable - I would definitely consider moving nearer to work, even if you have to pay some more.

Also remember that even 45-50 min per direction per day are more than 1.5 hours of your day, every day. Your waking time is already just 16 hours, so you basically cut it by 10%. Now, ok, you can maybe nap or read, but that's not very effective. So that actually costs quite a lot, even if not in terms of money.

If you do choose to commute - try to make the experience as smooth as possible for yourself, which may be even more important that the time spent:

- Bike on both sides: Consider a simple bike in each city; probably something simple and with a good lock so it doesn't get stolen. But you might prefer walking, since while it's slower, it's a little less stressful.
- Consider getting something like a neck pillow, eye cover, noise-damping ear buds - if you want to sleep; or invest in a good e-book reader if to want to read, so your eyes tire less. etc.